# How to download and convert .data file to .csv?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, io

I would like to download and convert a data file from the UCI machine learning repository (specifically this one: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Arrhythmia) to test a classifier with and I am unsure of how to do this.  I'm working with python/pandas as far as file parsing goes, is there some standard way of working with this kind of dataset?

Thanks for your input

Comment: The `.data` file is already a `.csv` file. You should be able to read it with `csv` or `pandas` out of the box

Comment: Gotcha, how exactly do I extract the file from the url?  Do I curl it into a file? @inspectorG4dget

Comment: Just right click, save as .txt, then convert to csv.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib`

```
import urllib

URL = "https://..."   # URL of your file

urllib.urlretrieve (URL, "myFile.csv")
```

Later you can use the csv module to manipulate the file